# Como puedo generar un archivo que posea una variable que quiero a partir de varios archivos

Tags: linux

Hola muy buenas soy nuevo en programacion y me mandaron a hacer un script que partiendo de varios archivos generados de un analisis (15645 para ser especificos) generar un archivo que contenga el valor "HA_RMSDm:" de esos 15645 archivos la verdad estoy en 0 en programacion me toco aprender por la fuerza asi que les pido su ayuda si me pueden decir si estoy bien o se q muy probablemente este mal pero en si lo que busco es un script que analice 15645 archivos y despues me genere un fichero con el valor "$HA_RMSDm:" de esos 15645 archivos esto es lo que estaba haciendo pueden insultarme no hay problema jeje pero estoy aprendiendo gracias por la ayuda de antemano y disculpen las faltas ortograficas mi teclado no tiene tildes y son las 4 am y no avanzo. Porfa ayuda

```css
#!/bin/bash


#RSMDm
#Total_elapsep_time

#Loop over nohub
for i in (1...15645) do
        if i -r "$HA_RMSDm" then
                cat| grep "$HA_RMSDm" do
                        "$FinalRMSDm".in
        done
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una comparación de cadena, algo así:

```
#!/bin/bash
    string1='$HA_RMSDm'
    for i in (1...15645) do
        if [[ $string1 = *$HA_RMSDm* ]];
        then
            [LO QUE SEA]
        else
            [LO QUE SEA] //si lo necesitas
        fi
```

Comment: El siguiente enlace podría serte util: https://bit.ly/2wDveXp